# How to nest maps and display them in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, map, related-list, loop

I need to display a a 4 level deep relation on a visualforce page from the parent showing the child relations.

Account>property__c>Booking__c>Order>OrderItem.

Since we can only go 1 level deep with soql I had to use maps to link the children with the maps. How do I nest these maps and display these in visualforce?

I have the following so far:

```
  accList = [SELECT id, name FROM Account WHERE id =:accID];
    propList = [SELECT id, name, account__c FROM Property__c WHERE account__c IN :accList];
    bookingList = [SELECT id, name, uidproperty__c FROM Booking__c WHERE uidproperty__c IN :propList];
    orderList = [SELECT id, Name, booking__c, (SELECT id, PricebookEntry.ProductCode from OrderItems ) FROM Order WHERE booking__c IN :bookingList];
    //Booking id, Order
    ordMap = new Map<id,Order>();
    for(Booking__c bk : bookingList){
        for(Order o : orderList){
            if(o.booking__c == bk.id){
                ordMap.put(bk.id,o);
            }
        }
    }
    system.debug('ordMap: '+ordMap);
    //Property id, Booking__c
    bookMap = new Map<id,Booking__c>();
    for(Property__c pro : propList){ 
        for(Booking__c bk1 : bookingList){  
            if(bk1.uidProperty__c == pro.id){
                bookMap.put(pro.id,bk1);
            }
        }
    }
    system.debug('bookMap: '+bookMap);
     //Account id, Property__c
    propMap = new Map<id,Property__c>();
    for(Account a : accList){ 
        for(Property__c p : propList){  
            if(p.account__c == a.id){
                propMap.put(a.id,p);
            }
        }
    }   
    system.debug('propMap: '+propMap);
```

UPDATE maps:

```
    //Account id, Property__c
    Map<Id, Property__c> propMap = new Map<Id, Property__c>([
        SELECT id, name, account__c
        FROM Property__c
        WHERE account__c IN :accList
    ]);
    system.debug('propMap: '+propMap);
     //Property__c id, Booking__c
    Map<Id, Booking__c> bookMap = new Map<Id, Booking__c>([
        SELECT id, name, uidproperty__c 
        FROM Booking__c 
        WHERE uidproperty__c IN :propList
    ]);
    system.debug('bookMap: '+bookMap);
    //Booking id, Order
       Map<Id, Order> ordMap = new Map<Id, Order>([
        SELECT id, Name, booking__c, 
           (SELECT id, PricebookEntry.ProductCode from OrderItems ) 
           FROM Order 
           WHERE booking__c IN :bookingList
    ]);
    system.debug('ordMap: '+ordMap);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pattern that can work better is to create a wrapper class that handles the parent/child relationships:

```
public class Node {

    public SObject sob {get; private set;}

    public Node parent {get; private set;}
    public Node[] children {get; private set;}

    public Node(SObject sob) {
        this.sob = sob;
        this.children = new Node[] {};
    }

    public Node addChild(Node child) {
        child.parent = this;
        children.add(child);
        return child;
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        return (Account) sob;
    }

    public Property__c getProperty() {
        return (Property__c) sob;
    }

    ...
}
```

so that in Visualforce you can loop over the nested collections like this:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!accounts} var="a">
    <apex:outputText value="{!a.account.Name"}/>
    ...
    <apex:repeat value="{!a.children}" var="p">
        <apex:outputText value="{!p.property.Name"}/>
        ...
        <apex:repeat value="{!p.children}" var="b">
            <apex:outputText value="{!b.booking.Name"}/>
            ...
            <apex:repeat value="{!b.children}" var="o">
                <apex:outputText value="{!o.order.Name"}/>
                ...
                <apex:repeat value="{!o.children}" var="oi">
                    <apex:outputText value="{!oi.orderItem.Name"}/>
                    ...
```

Also when building relationships, unless the number of rows involved will always be small, avoid this double nested loop pattern as its cost goes up exponentially with the number of records:

```
for(Booking__c bk : bookingList){
    for(Order o : orderList){
        if(o.booking__c == bk.id){
```

Best to use instead be matching using `Map<Id, Type>` and there is a convenience `Map` constructor to create those e.g.:

```
Map<Id, Property__c> properties = new Map<Id, Property__c>([
    SELECT id, name, account__c
    FROM Property__c
    WHERE account__c IN :accList
]);
```

Once you have these maps, you can find the matching object by its Id with one `get` operation rather than by having to loop over the whole collection.

Comment: I am new to wrapper classes I tried your example but get: Missing return statement required return type: Node. How do I add the queries In this case?

Comment: Hi @Thomas, I missed a line I've now added. On the queries, you would do those outside of this code and then add the results using this class.

Comment: Thanks @Keith. Could you explain a little bit further how to use this. How do I pas the queries to the wrapperclass and then to visualforce for for example the account and property?

Comment: Could jou explain further the return part of the Account?. Do I need to place the map into the method?

Comment: Sorry @Thomas very tied up in work this week.

Comment: I figured it out another way by nesting the maps then looping trough the maps and repeat on the lists filtered by map key. Though I am still interested into your solution how this works.

Comment: Can you find some time this week to further explain this approach? Thanks in advance